# Javascript : event is not calling submitted bind(..)-copy of callback :-/

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

bind() should return a copy of the original function.. Yet when passing this copy as a callback, the original function is called :-( Tested with Chrome, Firefox and Edge. So where is my error in reasoning ?

```
<html><body>
<script>    
// new api to wrap these nested Cordova callbacks ..
ScanDir = function (sPath, rCallback, iStep){
  yes = _Yes.bind(rCallback);   // should return a copy/newInstance of _Yes !?!
  yes.iStep = iStep;

  // simulate a cordova callback ..
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", yes);
}

_Yes = function YES(o){
    // this is not the new instance returned by bind(..):
    alert(_Yes.iStep);  // = undefined
    alert(YES.iStep);   // = undefined
    alert(arguments.callee.iStep);  // = undefined

    alert(yes.iStep); // wrong, 'yes' must not be global...
}
</script>
<span id="test">click here to trigger callback</span>
<script>
    // code that uses my new api..
    function Go(v){
        if (!v.iStep)   return ScanDir(v,Go,1);
        alert("continue with switch("+v.iStep+")");
    }

    Go("Music/");
</script>
</body></html>
```

debug the code here: http://www.robosoft.de/forums/bug.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be:

```
yes = _Yes.bind({callback:rCallback,iStep:iStep});
```

Inside _Yes you can access:

```
this.callback();
alert(this.iStep);
```

And no, bind does not create a new function, it binds the function...

Comment: No, bind() creates a new function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind . And already the last `alert(yes.iStep);` proves that the function object `yes` (submitted as the callback) is a different function object. 
Why is `_Yes = YES` called when `yes` was provided as the callback ???

And yes, i had allredy moved on with your soludion: `_Yes.bind({ "rCallback": rCallback, "iStep": iStep })` - Still i would like to understand that strange behavior of the given example.

Comment: Well i don't get the meaning of _**Description:**
The bind() function creates a new bound function (BF). A BF is an exotic function object (a term from ECMAScript 2015) that wraps the original function object. Calling a BF generally results in the execution of its wrapped function._ :-/ My example clearly proves two distinct function optjects `yes` and `YES`. `yes` is given as the callback but `YES` is called. I think this is weird.

Comment: @bornloser i think the best answer would be: simply dont assign propertys to function objects, except they are static functions...

Comment: Don't we assign properties to function objects all the time when oop: `function CFile(sRoot) {this.m_sRoot = sRoot;}` ??? I thought it was one of the innovations of Javascript that functions must not be static. And i posted this question after i had already moved on with the same solution you then offered. But this question is to understand that strange behavior.

Comment: @bornloser nope. this will refer to a newly created object... (function test(){ alert(this.doesntwork);}).doesntwork="not"; new test()

Comment: okay now i get it :-) a function (object) is rather a blueprint for doing something (calling the function) or returning a somehow more real object via the `new` operator: https://jsfiddle.net/qe9xbyh9/ The bind function here returns a new copy `yes` of the `_Yes` function but when the callback finally is called, only the referenced blueprint is used and this is still the original `_Yes` function. Still weird but i agree with you that we better expect functions as static objects.